# Magento 2 - cant enable template hints

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, save, template-hints

I try to enable template hints in **Stores -> Settings: Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Debug**

But if I make my changes and save, then it reloads and the settings are reseted to the values they had before the change.

I also tried it via CLI

```
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable
Template hints enabled.
```

but if I reload the settings site, then it is still set to disabled there. There are no errors in the browser console.

I checked the table "core_config_data":

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path LIKE "%template%"
```

[image]

As you can see it is enabled.

But if I reload the frontend with parameter `?templatehints=magento` e.g. **http://entwicklung.fresh.m2/besteck.html?templatehints=magento** then it does not show template hints. Of course I cleared the cache.

I am in **developer** mode, not production.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
Current application mode: developer. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)
```

I even updated to the latest version as of 2.3.5-p1

Comment: You can try chmod 777 (or 664) app/etc/env.php and run cache flush (```php bin/magento cache:flush```)

Comment: @bang.nguyen47, does not work. env.php has nothing to do with template hints.

Comment: Have you save the configuration after enabling Template Path Hints for Admin ?

Answer (score 0):

Before getting started:

1. Make sure your Magento 2 is in the default or developer mode.
2. Go to Admin Panel > Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug.
3. Check and configure Developer Client Restrictions.
4. Enable Template Path Hints.
5. Once you have finished don't forget to press the Save Config button.
6. Before using Template Path Hints we recommend you make sure that Magento block cache, page cache are disabled.

Let me know if this helps.